# ASP.Net MVC3 SQL Nullable

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, null, ef-code-first, data-annotations

I'm currently working on an ASP.Net MVC3 project. I have it set up so my sql database creates it's tables based off of classes I've created and I need to know if there's a way to set it so that the variables can be null for example:

```
   public class Cart
   {
       [Key]
       public int RecordId { get; set; }
       public string CartId { get; set; }
       public int VideoId { get; set; }
       public int CandyId { get; set; }
       public int Count { get; set; }
       public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
       public virtual Video Video { get; set; }
       public virtual Candy Candy { get; set; }
    }
```

Is there a way to set the VideoId and Candy Id so that they can be null? The way they're coming up right now is as foreign keys to other tables. Any and all help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Should `VideoId` *not* be the foreign key to the `Video` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `VideoId` and `CandyId` nullable using the `?` symbol:

```
public int? VideoId { get; set; }
public int? CandyId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1) Declare your properties using int?

```
 public int? VideoId { get; set; }
 public int? CandyId { get; set; }
```

2) Declare your properties using regular int, but handling what should happend when you get a null value.

```
 VideoId = thisMightBeNull ?? 0; //?? means, if the variable is null then use 0
```

Using the first option has the disadventage that if you want to assign VideoId or CandyId to a new variable it should be int?, and sometimes it gets messy.
With the second option you won't have that problem, but it means you should handle what to assign in that moment (default value).